# System namespace in another DLL

Tags: c#, .net, sterling-db

Here's my problem:

I am using a DLL library (not from the .NET framework) which contains a `System` namespace with the `Tuple` and `Lazy` classes.

When I try to compile my project the compiler throws some errors stating that these classes exist in `mscorlib.dll` and another DLL.

So, how can I use the classes from the .NET Framework and don't delete the reference to the other DLL?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543278/system-tuple-defined-in-multiple-assemblies)

Comment: What library is it?  You may not be able to use it with .NET 4.0 or greater.

Comment: I've added details on how to work around this, but I have to agree with the other people advising to update the reference to something targeted at 3.5/4.0/4.5

Comment: My Project (for WP7) using DLL for SterlingDb. And now I want to migrate this project to WP8.

Comment: Hi @RomanGolenok, I'm helping out on SterlingDB and am going to look into making DLLs for WP8. (See also http://sterling.codeplex.com/discussions/431349). As this is all done in free time, I can't give you an exact date on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If they have the same namespace etc, then the only way to disambiguate is to use an `extern alias`. In the solution explorer, change the `Aliases` property of this rogue reference to something else, for example `foo` (instead of `global`).

Now, in the class files where you need types from that assembly, you'll have to add (at the very top):

```
extern alias foo;
```

And then later down in the code you can use:

```
foo::Some.Namespace.TheType
```

or equally:

```
foo.Some.Namespace.TheType
```

Basically, the alias name becomes an extra level of disambiguation. The default alias, for reference, is `global`. Note also, however, that while the **compiler** is fine with this, the VS2012 IDE still has a few... *kinks* with `extern alias`: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770464/ide-but-not-compiler-incorrectly-reports-an-error-when-using-extern-alias-to-disambiguate-types

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like the third party library you're using was designed to be used for .NET 2.0 or .NET 3.5.

I'd be very surprised if the third party didn't *also* supply DLLs for .NET 4+ - I strongly suspect you can just replace the DLLs which the ones for your target framework version and rebuild.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a library targeted for .NET 2 or 3.5, which added own implementations for .NET 4 features ([`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) and [`Lazy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx)). Look for an updated .NET 4 version of this library.

Comment: I am not sure how one can speculate that the library was design to implement something that existed in new version of the .NET Framework.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't speculate, ... *the OP mentioned*, that it contains `Tuple` and `Lazy` classes in the corresponding namespaces.

Comment: Clarification is all I wanted.

Comment: @Ramhound OK. Now clear, why I to assumed that the library implemented .NET 4 features?